# release-start showing 'Working tree has uncommitted changes' but git status has 'nothing to commit'

Tags: git, jgit

I am trying to start a release using JGit and encounter the issue as below,

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal external.atlassian.jgitflow:jgitflow-maven-plugin:1.0-m5.1:release-start (default-cli) on project xxxxx: Error starting release: Error starting release: Working tree has uncommitted changes -> [Help 1]

But git status is showing as clean and nothing to commit.

```
$ git status
On branch development
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/development'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

how to fix this issue?

Comment: Are you trying to start the release on the same machine and in the same repo as where you ran the `git status` command?